# How to read a Json file with hyphenated properties

Tags: c#, json

I am learning c# and trying to read some json files. I've learnt how to read ok except when a property is hyphenated - I don't know how to model the json in order to deserialize it.

So if I had the following Json:

```json
{
    "prop1": "val1"
}
```

I would do this:

```cs
class MyJson
{
    public string prop1;
}

MyJson? myJson = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyJson>(jsonStr);
```

But if I had this Json:

```json
{
    "prop-1": "val1"
}
```

I obviously can't do this:

```cs
class MyJson
{
    public string prop-1;
}

MyJson? myJson = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<MyJson>(jsonStr);
```

So how would I deserialize the above Json with a hyphenated property?

I've found loads of great resources regarding reading and writing Json, but nothing that explains it when a property is hyphenated.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `[JsonPropertyName("name")]` attribute.
Use it above your property like this

```
class MyJson
{
    [JsonPropertyName("prop-1")]
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
}
```

While using `Newtonsoft`, use `[JsonProperty("name")]` attribute instead.

Comment: Although it should probably be a property rather than a field, and I'd suggest following .NET naming conventions, too...

Comment: It should actually be `[JsonPropertyName("prop-1")]` and works like a dream

Comment: @paulh I was convinced you were using `Newtonsoft`. I've made an edit to support `System.Text.Json` as well.

Comment: @Madhatter Yes sorry, I didn't realise the solution would differ between the two.